# Subscribe to ANCS on Android

Tags: android, ios, notifications, bluetooth-lowenergy, ancs

Based on the services listed [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/AppleNotificationCenterServiceSpecification/Specification/Specification.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013460-CH1-SW14), I'm trying to subscribe to a service from an Android device, but can't get the solicitation part working. Tried to advertise using `7905F431-B5CE-4E99-A40F-4B1E122D00D0` but the peripheral is not showing up on the iPhone's bluetooth devices list. Also played with (LE)scan and filters to discover the ANCS server without luck. Any hint?

edit: code

`BleService.java`

```
public void setCharacteristicNotification(BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic,
                                          boolean enabled) {
    Log.d(TAG, "setCharacteristicNotification");
    if (mBluetoothAdapter == null || mBluetoothGatt == null) {
        Log.w(TAG, "BluetoothAdapter not initialized");
        return;
    }
    mBluetoothGatt.setCharacteristicNotification(characteristic, enabled);
    BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor = characteristic.getDescriptor(UUID.fromString(SampleGattAttributes.DESCRIPTOR));
    descriptor.setValue(BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE);
    mBluetoothGatt.writeDescriptor(descriptor)
}

@Override
public void onServicesDiscovered(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status) {
    if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
        broadcastUpdate(ACTION_GATT_SERVICES_DISCOVERED);
    }
}
```

`SampleGattAttributes.java`

```
public class SampleGattAttributes {
    public static String ANCS_SERVICE = "7905F431-B5CE-4E99-A40F-4B1E122D00D0";
    public static String NOTIFICATION_SOURCE = "9FBF120D-6301-42D9-8C58-25E699A21DBD";
    public static String DATA_CONTROL = "22EAC6E9-24D6-4BB5-BE44-B36ACE7C7BFB";
    public static String DESCRIPTOR = "00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb";
}
```

`MainActivity.java`

```
private void displayServices(List<BluetoothGattService> services) {
    for (BluetoothGattService service : services) {
        if (service.getUuid().compareTo(UUID.fromString(ANCS_SERVICE)) == 0) {
            for (BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic : service.getCharacteristics()) {
                Log.d(TAG, "charac: " + characteristic.getUuid());
                for (BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor : characteristic.getDescriptors()) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "desc: " + descriptor.getUuid());
                }
                if (characteristic.getUuid().compareTo(UUID.fromString(NOTIFICATION_SOURCE)) == 0) {
                    bleService.setCharacteristicNotification(characteristic, true);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

private final BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        final String action = intent.getAction();
        if (BleService.ACTION_GATT_SERVICES_DISCOVERED.equals(action)) {
            displayServices(bleService.getSupportedGattServices());
        }
    }
};
```

update: I'm able to find the services and characteristics after connecting to a service advertised on the iPhone. However, subscribing to notifications doesn't trigger `onCharacteristicChanged` upon receiving a notification on the iPhone.

update2: all the write `descriptor.setValue` calls are successful, and run in sequence.

update3: used part of the code from [this sample.](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/7167a054a8027f75025c865322fa84791a9b3bd1/samples/BluetoothLeGatt/src/com/example/bluetooth/le/BluetoothLeService.java?autodive=0%2F)

update4: test devices: Nexus 5X Android 6.0.1; iPhone 6S+ iOS 10.3.1

update5: BT logs

write request
[image]

write response
[image]

Comment: well In Nexus devices go  On the developer options, there is one checkbox which is "Enable Bluetooth HCI snoop log". When you enable it, the device will log everything that's happening on the Bluetooth stack....see log stored in Sd card called "HCIsnoop.log". When you have your file on your HD, download this s/w (free): http://www.fte.com/support/download.aspx?demo=ComProbe%20SD&type=capture&iid=1v  to view these BT log file. With this u can see any packet that has been exchanged from one device to another (like a Wireshark for BT).

Comment: Any way you can post this application on Github? A simple ANCS Android client would be amazing

Comment: Was you able to get notifications from iOS on android?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oh I had a similar issue, make sure you don't use Local Notifications when testing on iOS as those won't be propagated through ANCS. You need real push notifications for whatever reason.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar issue recently. What I ended up doing to resolve it was adding a `writeDescriptor` to my `BluetoothGatt`. My `setCharacteristicNotification` now looks like this:

```
public void setCharacteristicNotification(BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, boolean enabled) {
if (mBluetoothAdapter == null || mBluetoothGatt == null) {
    Log.w(TAG, "BluetoothAdapter not initialized");
    return;
}
mBluetoothGatt.setCharacteristicNotification(characteristic, enabled);

BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor = characteristic.getDescriptor(
    UUID.fromString("00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"));
descriptor.setValue(BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE);
mBluetoothGatt.writeDescriptor(descriptor);
}
```

Perhaps if you could post/link your code I would be able to further diagnose your exact issue, but the above code was the solution to my problem.